# grails 2.5 dbm-update always fails with MissingMethodException if you specify any context

Tags: grails, liquibase

We always get an exception if specify any context with dbm-update, regardless of if that context has any changeSets or not.  If we specify no context, we get everything - it works, but obviously it creates data which is not appropriate.

As there is no actual example, we have tried many possible syntaxes commands on windows 8 (& java 7 64 bit, mysql 5.6), including:

```
grails dbm-update --stacktrace --verbose --contexts="ABC"
grails dbm-update --stacktrace --verbose "--contexts=ABC"
grails dbm-update --stacktrace --verbose "--contexts=[ABC]"
grails dbm-update --stacktrace --verbose --contexts=ABC
```

All variants give the following stack trace:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: liquibase.Liquibase.update() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [true]
Possible solutions: update(java.lang.String), update(int, java.lang.String), update(java.lang.String, java.io.Writer), u
pdate(int, java.lang.String, java.io.Writer), validate(), isCase(java.lang.Object)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
        at DbmUpdate$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(DbmUpdate:26)
        at DbmUpdate$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(DbmUpdate)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaM
ethodSite.java:207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:114)
        at _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2$_closure11.doCall(_DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy:59)
        at _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2$_closure11.doCall(_DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaM
ethodSite.java:207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:114)
        at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.executeInSession(MigrationUtils.groovy:133)
        at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils$executeInSession$3.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
```

NOTE: this is only a small fraction of the actual stacktrace.

The only change sets we have with contexts defined are like this:

```
<changeSet id="baseline_data_account_type_uk" author="me.me" context="UK">
    <comment>Insert UK account types</comment>
    <sqlFile path="sql//baseline//account_type_UK.sql" />
</changeSet>
```

If we don't specify any context on the dbm-update command line, it correctly runs the simple update SQL in this changeset no problem, so its not a problem with the changeset or changelog.

I have the "dbCreate=xxx" line removed in the dev dataSource of course.

Its a complete guess, but this may be related to the boolean type in the insert sql.  The above changeset refers to account_type_UK.sql, which is this:

```
INSERT INTO `account_type` (`id`, `version`, `is_default`, `name`) VALUES
(3, 0, b'1', 'Bonus'),
(4, 0, b'1', 'Demo');
```

The above works perfectly, correctly inserting the Data with no context specified.

Another clue is that if a context is specified, we get the missing method exception, but the schema is not created. This might imply that the problem is at the schema level. The schema is created with a single xml changelog generated with dbm-gorm-diff

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a version incompatibility between what Grails is calling and the version of Liquibase you have. Grails is looking for a version of update() which does not exist on the version of Liquibase you are using. Can you check which Liquibase version should be compatible with Grails 2.5?

Comment: Interestingly, in grails, the database migration plugin 1.4 comes as standard. However, there seems to be no liquibase defined which I can see - I dont know where it gets it from. I certainly dont have liquibase available on the command line of windows.

Comment: digging through the cache in home/.grails, it found liquibase-core-2.0.5.jar.  There is no mention of the version which the database migration 1.4.0 plugin expects (see https://grails.org/plugin/database-migration ) , but I assume its the correct one.

Comment: The problem seems to be that grail's DbmUpdate:26 is calling liquibase.Liquibase.update(true) which isn't a valid function in Liquibase 2.0.5. I'm not sure off hand if there is a release where that is a valid function or not. I'm guessing it's a bug in DbmUpdate